# Is it safe to use a file descriptor and its associated FILE* stream simultaneously?

Tags: c, sockets, select, getline, fdopen

I'm writing a C++ socket library to handle the intricacies of managing socket related system calls.  I'm curious if there are any harmful side effects in creating a `FILE*` with [`fdopen(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fdopen) and using it alongside the client's original file descriptor.

I'd like to be able to do this because it provides greater flexibility in being able to use things such as [`select(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) while also using [`getline(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getline) (the primary goal of this question), however I fear that the `FILE*` will cause some issues with file descriptor based utilities (namely the internal buffering of a `FILE*` messing with [`select(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select)'s ability to determine if there is data available for [`read(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read)).

Comment: see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589168/getline-over-a-socket

Comment: Here's what the standard says: [Interaction of File Descriptors and Standard I/O Streams](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_05.html#tag_02_05_01)

Comment: @SedatKapanoglu The answers to this question don't really address the topic stated in the linked question; it merely warns against logical problems if such a function were to exist for a file descriptor.  One of the answers did however suggest that keeping a custom buffer might be necessary for such functionality which is something that I'm not opposed to writing but doesn't address this question specifically.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick So would it be safe to use a `FILE*` and file descriptor simultaneously if I made the `FILE*` unbuffered?

Comment: @ClayFreeman if you only needed `FILE*` for "`getline`", the answer I pointed at says "don't -- not a good idea". that's why I shared it with you.

Comment: @ClayFreeman Probably, if you take care of this if necessary (and I don't think it'll be necessary if the fd is a socket, because that isn't seekable): *If the stream is open with a mode that allows reading and the underlying open file description refers to a device that is capable of seeking, the application shall either perform an fflush(), or the stream shall be closed.*

Comment: In my tests on Linux with eglibc and on FreeBSD 10, `getline` on an unbuffered stream created from a socket called its `read`s with a *count* arg of 1, which is fine. But I think it's a good idea to test this on all your systems, to see whether `getline` will read beyond the end of a line. If it does, then as you say, it could throw off a subsequent `select`.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick So essentially `getline` for an unbuffered stream would be just as inefficient as `fgetc` in a loop?  I might as well just write my own buffer for this.

Comment: That sounds reasonable.